# The difference between topological combinatorics and combinatorial topology?

Tags: combinatorics

Both terms are used to call branches in which Combinatorics and Topology are combined. I guess that in Topological Combinatorics, Combinatorics comes first (i.e. the initial problem is purely Combinatorics) and Topology is used as a tool to tackle with this problem. Meanwhile, in Combinatorial Topology, Topology comes first (i.e. the problem is purely Topology, motivated by theories in Topology) and Combinatorics can be similarly used. In general, if we talk about the connection between two branches [X], [Y], [X]al [Y] can be understood as "using [X] to solve problem in [Y]". For example, Algebraic Geometry means using Algebra to deal with Geometry problem.
It is just my guess according to what I know about different branches in Mathematics. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much, although combinatorial topology is more well known as algebraic topology now, since the concepts around this field changed from combinatorial to algebraic ones.

Outside of that yes, combinatorial topology used things like topological invariants (which were originally regarded as a combinatorial aspect, but later changed according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_topology)) to prove things about topology, while topological combinatorics uses algebraic (or combinatorial) topology to solve combinatorial problems, with methods like the Borsuk-Ulam theorem to prove the Kneser conjecture, which proves a formula for the chromatic number for any Kneser graph, a fully combinatorial focused problem.

Also in general yes, [X] [Y] field means methods from X are used on Y types of problems. Like analytic number theory uses methods of analysis on number theoretic problems, like Dirichlet series and the Riemann-Zeta function.